# @OneToMany sem Primary Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Existe a possibilidade de fazer uma relação `@OneToMany` sem *Primary Key* na tabela filha?

Segue as minhas duas entidades.

Entidade `Noticia`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTICIA")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Noticia.findAll", query = "SELECT n FROM Noticia n"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Noticia.findAllByDate", query = "SELECT n FROM Noticia n WHERE n.dhCadastro BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
})
public class Noticia implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cdNoticia")
    private Long cdNoticia;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cdVeiculo")
    private long cdVeiculo;
    @Column(name = "nmAutor")
    private String nmAutor;
    @Column(name = "cdColunista")
    private Short cdColunista;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cdSecao")
    private short cdSecao;
    @Column(name = "dsTitulo")
    private String dsTitulo;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "dsTexto")
    private String dsTexto;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "dsURL")
    private String dsURL;
    @Column(name = "cdHash")
    private String cdHash;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "dtNoticia")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dtNoticia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "hrNoticia")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date hrNoticia;
    @Column(name = "dhCadastro")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dhCadastro;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idTipo")
    private String idTipo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idDigitalizada")
    private String idDigitalizada;

    @Column(name = "isTransicao")
    private Integer isTransicao;

    @Column(name = "isElasticSearch")
    private Integer isElasticSearch;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "noticia", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Noticiaimagem> noticiaimagemCollection = new ArrayList<Noticiaimagem>();



    public Noticia() {
    }

    public Long getCdNoticia() {
        return cdNoticia;
    }

    public void setCdNoticia(Long cdNoticia) {
        this.cdNoticia = cdNoticia;
    }

    public long getCdVeiculo() {
        return cdVeiculo;
    }

    public void setCdVeiculo(long cdVeiculo) {
        this.cdVeiculo = cdVeiculo;
    }

    public String getNmAutor() {
        return nmAutor;
    }

    public void setNmAutor(String nmAutor) {
        this.nmAutor = nmAutor;
    }

    public Short getCdColunista() {
        return cdColunista;
    }

    public void setCdColunista(Short cdColunista) {
        this.cdColunista = cdColunista;
    }

    public short getCdSecao() {
        return cdSecao;
    }

    public void setCdSecao(short cdSecao) {
        this.cdSecao = cdSecao;
    }

    public String getDsTitulo() {
        return dsTitulo;
    }

    public void setDsTitulo(String dsTitulo) {
        this.dsTitulo = dsTitulo;
    }

    public String getDsTexto() {
        return dsTexto;
    }

    public void setDsTexto(String dsTexto) {
        this.dsTexto = dsTexto;
    }

    public String getDsURL() {
        return dsURL;
    }

    public void setDsURL(String dsURL) {
        this.dsURL = dsURL;
    }

    public String getCdHash() {
        return cdHash;
    }

    public void setCdHash(String cdHash) {
        this.cdHash = cdHash;
    }

    public Date getDtNoticia() {
        return dtNoticia;
    }

    public void setDtNoticia(Date dtNoticia) {
        this.dtNoticia = dtNoticia;
    }

    public Date getHrNoticia() {
        return hrNoticia;
    }

    public void setHrNoticia(Date hrNoticia) {
        this.hrNoticia = hrNoticia;
    }

    public Date getDhCadastro() {
        return dhCadastro;
    }

    public void setDhCadastro(Date dhCadastro) {
        this.dhCadastro = dhCadastro;
    }

    public String getIdTipo() {
        return idTipo;
    }

    public void setIdTipo(String idTipo) {
        this.idTipo = idTipo;
    }

    public String getIdDigitalizada() {
        return idDigitalizada;
    }

    public void setIdDigitalizada(String idDigitalizada) {
        this.idDigitalizada = idDigitalizada;
    }

    public Integer getIsTransicao() {
        return isTransicao;
    }

    public void setIsTransicao(Integer isTransicao) {
        this.isTransicao = isTransicao;
    }

    public Integer getIsElasticSearch() {
        return isElasticSearch;
    }

    public void setIsElasticSearch(Integer isElasticSearch) {
        this.isElasticSearch = isElasticSearch;
    }

    public List<Noticiaimagem> getNoticiaimagemCollection() {
        return noticiaimagemCollection;
    }

    public void setNoticiaimagemCollection(List<Noticiaimagem> noticiaimagemCollection) {
        this.noticiaimagemCollection = noticiaimagemCollection;
    }
}
```

Entidade `Noticiaimagem`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTICIAIMAGEM")
public class Noticiaimagem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cdNoticia", nullable = false)
    @MapsId
    private Noticia noticia;

    @Column
    private String nmImagem;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nmExtensao;

    @Column
    private Float nrTamanho;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED SMALLINT(5)")
    private Integer nrAltura;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED SMALLINT(5)")
    private Integer nrLargura;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED TINYINT(3)")
    private Integer nrOrdem;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT(8)")
    private Integer cdTipoNoticiaImagem;

    public Noticiaimagem() {
    }

    public Noticia getNoticia() {
        return noticia;
    }

    public void setNoticia(Noticia noticia) {
        this.noticia = noticia;
    }

    public String getNmImagem() {
        return nmImagem;
    }

    public void setNmImagem(String nmImagem) {
        this.nmImagem = nmImagem;
    }

    public String getNmExtensao() {
        return nmExtensao;
    }

    public void setNmExtensao(String nmExtensao) {
        this.nmExtensao = nmExtensao;
    }

    public Float getNrTamanho() {
        return nrTamanho;
    }

    public void setNrTamanho(Float nrTamanho) {
        this.nrTamanho = nrTamanho;
    }

    public Integer getNrAltura() {
        return nrAltura;
    }

    public void setNrAltura(Integer nrAltura) {
        this.nrAltura = nrAltura;
    }

    public Integer getNrLargura() {
        return nrLargura;
    }

    public void setNrLargura(Integer nrLargura) {
        this.nrLargura = nrLargura;
    }

    public Integer getNrOrdem() {
        return nrOrdem;
    }

    public void setNrOrdem(Integer nrOrdem) {
        this.nrOrdem = nrOrdem;
    }

    public Integer getCdTipoNoticiaImagem() {
        return cdTipoNoticiaImagem;
    }

    public void setCdTipoNoticiaImagem(Integer cdTipoNoticiaImagem) {
        this.cdTipoNoticiaImagem = cdTipoNoticiaImagem;
    }
}
```

O banco de dados é legado e não posso alterar sua estrutura. A tabela `NOTICIAIMAGEM` possui mais de 6 milhões de registros em produção. A mesma tabela não possui *Primary Key* e nem *Foreing Key*. O código acima foi gerado automaticamento pelo gerador de entidades do NetBeans.

Comment: O campo `nmImagem` da `Noticiaimagem` é o que? Se você der um `SELECT x.c FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM noticiaimagem ni GROUP BY ni.cd_noticia, ni.nm_imagem) x WHERE x.c > 1`, ele volta algum resultado?

Comment: @VictorStafusa, é o caminho da imagem; Retorna.

Answer (score 1):

O que você está tentando modelar é o seguinte:

> Uma notícia tem N figuras.

Como isso funciona no banco de dados?

> A tabela de figuras deve ter uma chave **estrangeira** da notícia.

O que está em sua modelagem?

> A tabela de figuras tem como chave **primária** a chave estrangeira da notícia.

Vez que a chave estrangeira também está como chave primária sem a participação de nenhum outro campo, você acabou criando um modelo que no banco de dados impede de haver mais de uma imagem associada a uma notícia, pois a chave das duas é a mesma. O fato de você colocar um `@ManyToOne` não vai fazer com que o Hibernate seja capaz de resolver isso, pois o seu modelo de banco de dados está furado.

Assim sendo, sugiro que a solução seja simplesmente separar os conceitos: A chave primária da imagem deve ser independente da chave estrangeira para a notícia. Isso resolverá os seus problemas. Eis o código correspondente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTICIAIMAGEM")
public class NoticiaImagem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cdImagem", nullable = false)
    private Long cdImagem;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cdNoticia", nullable = false)
    private Noticia noticia;

    // Resto do código ...
}
```

Observe que mudei o nome da classe para `NoticiaImagem` ao invés de `Noticiaimagem`.

O relacionamento inverso, na classe `Noticia` parece estar correto:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "noticia", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Noticiaimagem> noticiaimagemCollection = new ArrayList<Noticiaimagem>();
```

Mas eu mudaria o nome dele:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "noticia", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<NoticiaImagem> imagens = new ArrayList<>(10);
```

Há ainda outros problemas no seu código. Você usa em alguns lugares a anotação `@Column` sem especificar nada nela, o que não vai fazer nada. Você também especifica em alguns lugares `@Basic(optional = true)` quando seria melhor e mais fácil colocar o `nullable = false` na `@Column` correspondente.

Evite utilizar setters para setar coleções inteiras e utilizar getters que retornem coleções mutáveis. O motivo disso é que isso permite com que o seu encapsulamento possa ser facilmente violado, uma vez que a sua classe `Noticia` ao invés de estar gerenciando e encapsulando as imagens que fazem parte da notícia, está de fato abrindo mão de fazer esta tarefa e confiando-a cegamente a outrem. O melhor seria fazer algo assim na sua classe `Noticia`:

```
public List<NoticiaImagem> getImagens() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(imagens));
}

public void adicionarImagem(NoticiaImagem imagem) {
    Noticia outra = imagem.getNoticia();
    if (outra != this) {
        if (outra != null) outra.removerImagem(imagem);
        imagem.setNoticia(this);
    } else if (!imagens.contains(imagem)) {
        imagens.add(imagem);
    }
}

public void removerImagem(NoticiaImagem imagem) {
    imagens.remove(imagem);
    if (imagem.getNoticia() == this) imagem.setNoticia(null);
}
```

E isso em sua classe `NoticiaImagem`:

```
public void setNoticia(Noticia noticia) {
    this.noticia = noticia;
    if (noticia != null) noticia.adicionarImagem(this);
}

public Noticia getNoticia() {
     return noticia;
}
```

A ideia aqui é que ao utilizar o `getImagens()`, a lista retornada seja imutável, pois tentar modificá-la seria uma forma errada de tentar adicionar ou excluir uma figura à lista, e por isso temos o `Collections.unmodifiableList`. Por outro lado, se a lista for modificada por meio dos métodos `adicionarImagem(NoticiaImagem)` ou `removerImagem(NoticiaImagem)`, efeitos colaterais súbitos em qualquer lugar que tenham chamado o `getImagens()` anteriormente são indesejados, e é por isso que o `getImagens()` faz uma cópia da lista (com o `new ArrayList<>(imagens)`), pois assim mudanças na lista original não causarão efeitos colaterais na lista retornada pelo getter. Observe que não há um setter, e portanto não é possível corromper-se a lista de imagens ao montar-se uma lista mal formada e colocá-la na `Noticia`.

Já os métodos `adicionarImagem(NoticiaImagem)`, `removerImagem(NoticiaImagem)` e `setNoticia(Noticia)` chamam uns aos outros para garantir que se, e somente se, uma imagem pertence a uma notícia então tal notícia conterá esta imagem em sua lista e nenhuma outra notícia conterá esta imagem em sua lista. Também é necessário garantir que uma mesma imagem só apareça uma única vez na lista de imagens da notícia na qual ela aparece.

O método `adicionarImagem(NoticiaImagem)` em especial é o mais complexo para se fazer de forma correta, pois é necessário que ele seja projetado lembrando-se que ele pode acabar por chamar a si mesmo de forma recursiva indireta por meio do `setNoticia(Noticia)`.

Por fim, voltando a sua pergunta original:

> Existe a possibilidade de fazer uma relação `@OneToMany` sem *Primary Key* na tabela filha?

A resposta é que talvez até exista, mas mesmo se existir, isso seria uma péssima ideia e resultaria em um modelo furado, confuso e cheio de problemas. Não tente fazer isso. Ao invés de tentar fazer isso, corrija o seu modelo e então você não vai nem precisar pensar em fazer isso.

Comment: Então, esqueci de descrever um grande detalhe. Ante de tudo, o banco é legado. A tabela NOTICIAIMAGEM possui mais de 6 milhões de registro. A mesma tabela não possui PrimaryKey e nem ForeingKey....
Sobre o nome das classes, anotação Basic e os Getters e Setters, eu usei o gerador de entidade do Netbeans. Já a Column, eu não especifiquei o nome dos campos, porque as variáveis seguem os mesmo nome dos campos da tabela....

Comment: Estou tentando resolver esse problema a 3 dias... Cheguei a conclusão que pela modelagem do banco, acaba sendo mais viável usar JDBC. Achei bem interessante; A explicação de não usar getters e setters para coleções, achei bem interessante....